# Restrict types that may implement a Trait

Tags: oop, groovy, traits

Is it possible to restrict the types that can implement a trait? Say, for example I have a type

```
interface Something {
  void foo() 
}
```

and a trait

```
trait SomethingAbility {
  void bar()  {
    println "bar"
  }
}
```

Is there a way that I can only allow the trait to be implemented by classes that are of type `Something`, e.g.

```
// OK
class SomethingImpl implements Something, SomethingAbility {
  void foo() {
    println "foo"
  }
}

// error: this class should not be allowed to implement the trait
// because it's not a Something
class NotSomething implements SomethingAbility {
  void foo() {
    println "foo"
  }
}
```

One option is to add an abstract method to the trait

```
trait SomethingAbility {
  void bar() {
    println "bar"
  }

  abstract void foo()
}
```

This will mean that the trait can't be implemented by a class unless that class also provides a `foo()` method, but this isn't the same thing as the class being of type `Something`

Comment: make `SomethingAbility` implement `Something`?

Comment: @cfrick no.....I want to be sure that I can call methods of `Something` from `SomethingAbility`, but `SomethingAbility` itself does not need to be a `Something`

Comment: if quacks like a duck... ;P yet it think your final example and the last sentence should be about abstract `foo` and not `bar`?

Comment: but of course Groovy can be statically compiled, which means you can't rely on duck typing. I've fixed the error you highlighted - thanks

Comment: well maybe i am to far off into dynamic land, but isn't saying that SomeAbility only working if mixed with Some the same as saying, that SomeAb needs to fulfill the Some contract itself and thus implementing (which means extending for traits) a valid approach? before you write your abstract methods there that are error prone to change, i'd rather have the interface doing the job.

Comment: I don't like the abstract method approach either. I also don't like this approach `SomethingAbility implement Something` because it isn't `SomethingAbility` that needs to be a `Something`, but rather the class that implements the trait

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is @Selftype, see http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/SelfType.html
Basically it states what a class using this trait has to implement. So with

```
@SelfType(Something)
trait SomethingAbility {
   void bar()  {
     println "bar"
   }
}
```

you declare, that any class using this trait will also have to implement the interface Something. This ensures for example, that if you statically compile the trait and you call a method from the interface Something, that compilation will not fail. of course for standard Groovy this is not required, because of duck typing.